# USB PORT: How to Do i read data from usb port through browser windows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a device which sends data to computer USB device. so how do I access that data in the browser as the data is being received by doclight application but I can not get any response in the browser.

I have tried many ways but I did not found an information

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php

https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport

[How to read serial port data from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549151/how-to-read-serial-port-data-from-javascript)

so kindly help use we also tried the following code.

Comment: *How to read serial port data from javascript?* This explains it quite good???

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing. The only way to get it into the browser is through a backend. Node-serialPort is good for this (with an Arduino, Edison etc). If you are just using a browser however, I had my USB device create a CSV, which I uploaded to the webpage giving access to any data it logged.

[Here](https://github.com/Driptap/quitstik_2) is a project using Node-Webkit to interface with an Arduino board. It's not very well documented but you'll be able to see a working Node-serialPort implementation.